# Add an action result cache with a file dependency in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using .NET Framework 4.5.1 and ASP.NET MVC 5.

I have the following action:

```
    [OutputCache(Duration = 86400 /* 24 hours */, VaryByParam = "none")]
    public PartialViewResult WhatsNew()
    {
        var viewModel = new WelcomeWhatsNewViewModel
        {
            WhatsNewHeadlines = _service.GetWhatsNewHeadlines()
        };
        return PartialView("WhatsNew", viewModel);
    }
```

I am unclear on how I can add an action result cache with a file dependency, so that the cache is cleared when the razor view is updated. Is this possible?

I had a look through the ASP.NET MVC 5 source code but I couldn't see how to achieve this, and I did a bit of searching online yet failed to find anything explaining if this can be achieved or not.

Comment: Won't ASP.NET clear the cache when you redeploy?

Comment: We don't use Web Deploy for minor HTML changes to avoid having to restart the application pool.

Comment: Why would you change the Razor view on the server?

Comment: We are porting over legacy software which is over 12 years old in incremental stages, therefore some of the content will continue to be stored in views until we get to the sprint in which we implement a database for storing the content elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you modify a cshtml file, the next request will force a recompilation and the app domain will need to be unloaded, so httpruntime cache will be cleared which is what backs the outputcache. If for some reason this isn't happening.

Here is how you add cache dependency in your action

```
Response.AddCacheDependency(new CacheDependency(filename));
```